# How can I make a living audio streaming with node server?

Tags: javascript, audio, socket.io, live-streaming, internet-radio

I want to make a living audio streaming. I pipe my mp3 file from node server, there is a no problem. I play the mp3 on the client side but it just plays when the stream ends. I want to play it when the stream continues. How can I do it?

**Server Side**

```
   var stream = ss.createStream();
        ss(socket).emit('H_to_S_shareVoice', stream);
        var filename = 'musix' + '.mp3';
        console.log(filename);
        fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(stream);
```

**Client**

```
<br>
<br>
<h1 id='socket'>not connected</h1>
<br>
<audio autoplay volume="1" controls id="audio" />
```

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');


            socket.on("connect", function () {
                console.log("on connect");
                document.getElementById('socket').innerHTML = 'connected to the server';

                ss(socket).on('H_to_S_shareVoice', function (stream, data) {
                    console.log('received', data);

                    var binaryString = "";
                    stream.on('data', function (data) {
                        console.log('data')
                        console.log(data.length)
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            binaryString += String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
                        }
                        $("#audio").attr("src", "data:audio/wav;base64," + window.btoa(binaryString));
                        document.getElementById('audio').load();
                        document.getElementById('audio').play();
                        //document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = window.btoa(binaryString);
                        /*if (dat.length > 0 && oneTime) {
                            oneTime = false;

                        }*/
                        //  $("#audio").attr("src", "data:audio/wav;base64," + window.btoa(binaryString));


                        binaryString = ""
                    });

                    /*stream.on('end', function (data) {
                        console.log('end')
                        document.write(binaryString);
                        $("#audio").attr("src", "data:audio/wav;base64," + window.btoa(binaryString));

                        binaryString = "";
                    });*/
                });
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed with PCMPlayer.

```
var player = new PCMPlayer({
                        encoding: '16bitInt',
                        channels: 2,
                        sampleRate: 16000,
                        flushingTime: 1000
                    });
                    stream.on('data', function (data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        player.feed(data);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop all the Socket.IO code, and the whole base64 encoding mess...

All you have to do is output the media data over HTTP when the request comes in.  Your client code is as simple as `<audio src="path/on/the/server"></audio>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed it with PCMPlayer.

Comment: @oguzkaganeren That's unfortunate... that's going to use a ton of bandwidth.

Comment: Can I send different data to each client with your way? Can you suggest any source?